# Mapping a URL between Apache and Tomcat, using mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu, url-rewriting, mod-jk

I am using `Apache/2.2.14` and `Apache Tomcat/6.0.29` in a `Ubuntu Server 10.04.3 LTS`.

This is my `jk.conf`:

```
JkWorkersFile /etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties
JkMount       /portal/* worker1
JkLogLevel    debug
JkMountCopy   All
```

And this is my `workers.properties`:

```
ps=/

# Define 1 real worker named worker1
worker.list=worker1

# Set properties for worker named worker1 to use ajp13 protocol,
# and run on port 8009
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1
worker.worker1.socket_keepalive=1
worker.worker1.socket_timeout=300
```

The problem is that whenever I try to access tomcat via apache with: http://my.host.com/portal, tomcat replies with:

```
13:39:30,683 INFO  [PortalImpl:3829] Current URL /portal/ generates exception: null
```

The problem goes away if I use a different mountpoint for the worker:

```
JkMount       /portal/* worker1
```

But this forces me to access my tomcat instance here: http://my.host.com, which I do not want.

Is there any way of rewriting the URL using `mod-jk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip all that configuration if you just use mod_proxy instead of mod_ajp...

```
ProxyPass /foo http://localhost:8080/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:8080/bar
```

This will proxy /foo to local server URL /bar running on port 8080.

Comment: This works if I do `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080` and `ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080`. I can access the website at http://my.host.com. But if I try: `ProxyPass /portal http://localhost:8080` and `ProxyPassReverse /portal http://localhost:8080` and access http://my.host.com/portal, only part of the content is shown. Parts are not found because they are lacking the prefix `portal`. I would say that the problem is that tomcat doesn't add the prefix to the dynamic content. But actually this should be apache's responsability, to make it completely transparent for tomcat. Any hints?